# What does "++" mean in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I've been learning PHP by reading all sorts of things on the web. I've trying to figure out what this is called so I can look it up and read about it and learn how it works. It's the "++" in the code I'm assuming counts up so that the codes knows when to do a new line. I not looking for corrections to this code I'm looking for what the "++" is called so I can look it up.

```
$i = 0
if (++$i == 10) {
    echo "new line";
}
```

Comment: @animuson Valid point, but he could just as easily have searched for "++operator php" and came up empty.

Comment: @AnPel: That's why we close them as duplicates. So people can search, find this, then get directed to the resource that has all this information. Duplicates are kept in-tact as an "alternate route" to the duplicated question.

Answer (score 5):

It's called the **prefix increment unary operator**. It increments the number or character, then returns its value.

The postfix version does pretty much the same but returns its value first, then increments the variable.

Comment: Thank you both from your quick answers now I can find it and read more about it!

Answer (score 1):

That is a pre-increment. So in that code, `$i` is first incremented (increased by one), and then its value is used to test for equality to 10.

So the code that you show essentially tests if 1 equals 10 (which it does not.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a number operator named the prefix increment. It takes the previous stated number and adds 1 to it. You can find more information about arithmatic operators here: [Howtoforge.com](http://www.howtoforge.com/operators_in_php)

Answer (score 0):

It's the pre-increment operator. It will add one to the variable it precedes, and return the result. The post-increment operator returns the current value, and then adds one. The PHP Manuel has an article on all of the operators.

[All PHP Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)
[Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)